# How to use an Elasticsearch gauss function with min value but no max value, but still get results below min with reduced score?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Im trying to create a pretty complex query in Elasticsearch and have run into a little problem. Hopefully someone can help shed some light...

I have a price value which can be defined with a minimum value and/or a maximum value, or neither. When a min **and** max are defined its easy to use the `gauss` function to get results between the min and max with a score of 1, and a decreasing score for anything outside of the defined range...

```
"gauss": {
    "price_amount": {
        "origin": 150000,
        "offset": 50000,
        "scale": 10000
    }
}
```

However, when **only** the min **or** max is defined its a little trickier.

So for example, a user defines the price as a range: 100,000 - no max

How would I construct this as an Elasticsearch query in order to give a consistent score to anything above 100,000, but also pick up documents with a price below 100,000, but with a penalised score (like you get when using the `gauss` function within a `function_score` query)?

Ive thought of filtering the results by price first (before using the `gauss` function) but if I set the `gte` to range query value to the min (100,000), then this would exclude anything below 100,000. I could reduce the value I assign to the `gte` query to capture documents below 100,000, maybe setting it to 75,000, but this doesn't feel right...

Also, using the gauss function would reduce the score as the price increases, after the offset, which isnt what I need. I want a consistent score above the min (in this example), and a decaying score below 100,000.

Any guidance would be very appreciated.

Thanks
Lee

Answer (score 0):

Since posting I actually figured out the answer. So posting incase anyone comes across this...

The function inside a function_score query only influences the score of the documents, and you can control which documents you effect with the function by using a filter alongside the function.

So the solution to my problem was to filter as follows:

```
"query": {
    "function_score": {
      "min_score": 1e-12,
      "functions": [
        { ... },
        {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "price_amount": {
                "lte": 100000
              }
            }
          },
          "gauss": {
            "price_amount": {
              "origin": 100000,
              "offset": 0,
              "scale": 5000
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "query": {
        "constant_score": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                [
                  ...
                ]
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

This uses the gauss bell curve and reduces the score of documents where the price is less than 100,000. The offset is 0 so the score begins to decay straight away as we are already below the minimum value defined by the user, in this example.